# How can I fix this site for firefox?

Tags: html, css

I have this site:

http://www.invata.dac-proiect.ro/invat/pagina2.html

See how it looks Firefox browser page ...on Chrome is OK.

http://i59.tinypic.com/2qkm981.jpg

**CODE HTML:**

```
<div class="container-home" style="width: 1200px;height: 929px;background: url(DECUPATE/TEST/BACKGROUND.png);margin: 0 auto;background-size: contain;position:relative;">
      <div class="maimuta"><img src="DECUPATE/TEST/images/MAIMUTA.png" alt="Mountain View"></div>
      <div class="capitol"><p>Capitol:CAP.1 NUMERELE NATURALE DE LA 0 la 1.000</p></div>


<div class="problema">
   <p class="problema" style="
    float: left;
">Care din urmatoarele numere este mai mare: <br>307 100, 10 000, 51 000.<br>
<input style="margin-top:16px;" placeholder="Aici poti scrie rezultatul... " type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity">&nbsp;<span id="errmsg"></span>
</p>
  <img style="width:500px;" src="http://invata.dac-proiect.ro/imagini/1.png">




  <textarea placeholder="Aici poti scrie rezolvarea... " rows="4" cols="50" style="width: 340px; 
    margin: -227px 0px 0px 84px; height: 150px;"></textarea>
<a href="#"><p style="margin-left: 296px;margin-top: -73px;font-size: 13px;color:white;">Apeleaza indicatii</p></a>
  <a href="pagina3.html"><div class="intrebare"></div></a>


  <ul>
<li><img src="DECUPATE/TEST/images/BILA.png" style="width:35px;height:35px;"></li>
<li><img src="DECUPATE/TEST/images/BILA-ALBA.png" style="width:35px;height:35px;"></li>
<li><img src="DECUPATE/TEST/images/BILA-ALBA.png" style="width:35px;height:35px;"></li>
<li><img src="DECUPATE/TEST/images/BILA-ALBA.png" style="width:35px;height:35px;"></li>
<li><img src="DECUPATE/TEST/images/BILA-ALBA.png" style="width:35px;height:35px;"></li>
</ul> 


</div>

</div>
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You have no griding system. You need to work on that.

You should have two colums:

1. for the right side with the drawing
2. for the left side with the text and form.

so, do this:

```
<div class="column-left">
  <p class="problema" style="
    float: left;
">Care din urmatoarele numere este mai mare: <br>307 100, 10 000, 51 000.   

  <br>
  <input style="margin-top:16px;" placeholder="Aici poti scrie rezultatul... " type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity">&nbsp;<span id="errmsg"></span>
  </p>
  <textarea placeholder="Aici poti scrie rezolvarea... " rows="4" cols="50" style="width: 340px; 
    margin: -227px 0px 0px 84px; height: 150px;"></textarea>
  <a href="#"><p style="margin-left: 296px;margin-top: -73px;font-size: 13px;color:white;">Apeleaza indicatii</p></a>
  <a href="pagina3.html"><div class="intrebare"></div></a>
</div>

<div class="column-right">
  <img style="width:500px;" src="http://invata.dac-proiect.ro/imagini/1.png">
</div>
```

then in your css you do this:

```
.column-left, column-right {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

that should do the trick. then you can customize your css of course and improve it to have some margins/paddings in between.

Answer (score 0):

Give `float: left;` also to the `textarea`.